# Ecllipse not opening in Linux

Tags: linux

I have installed oepe-12.1.2.3-kepler-distro-linux-gtk-x86_64.zip in my Linux build server.

However I am getting the below error while launching it.

org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [gtk_init_check() failed]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a problem in your libgtk. Please take a look at this link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94497/org-eclipse-swt-swterror-no-more-handles-gtk-init-check-failed-while-runnin